# Toggle entire div is unresponsive

Tags: jquery, html

I have a submit button that currently runs 2 functions, but will later on run 3.

1. Hide paragraph on click
2. Onclick make div into toggle (Make itself into a toggle).
3. Insert data into DB.

I have successfully completed task 1, I am working on task 2 however now that i have added the onclick onto the button for task 2 onclick the page becomes white, and everything disappears.

So my question is, is it possible to toggle a entire div and everything within it. The idea is the moment the user enters the products name and description and clicks on add. The entire div will be made into a toggle.

```js
//turn entire div into toggle
            function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
                    e.style.display = 'none';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'block';
            }

  //hide text onclick
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $p = $('p#menu_title');
                $("input#save_first_prod").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $p.css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: visible; 
}
div#first_product{
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
    
}

div#red_head{
background-color: #ed1c24;
height: 40px;
color: #fff;
padding-left: 15px;
line-height: 35px;
}

div#first_product{
background-color: #f1f1f2; 
height: 100%;
}

h3#menu{
color: #6d6e70;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
        

<div id="first_product">
            <div id="red_head">
                <p id="menu_title" class ="hidden" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
            </div>
            <h3 id="menu">Menu Section</h3>

            <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               

                <label id="cat_label" name="cat_label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" value="">

                <label id="desc_label" name="desc_label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_desc" name="cat_desc" value="">

                <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')" value=" + ADD"> 

            </form>


        </div>
```

Task 1, which was removing the "Add your first menu item" worked, until i added the 2nd toggle, is it not possible to have more than 1 function on each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole page goes white because you are toggling the whole page because the div is the whole page. So now we know why the screen goes blank. If you added a button outside the div, then you could toggle it. Hopefully this helps.

```js
//turn entire div into toggle
            function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
                    e.style.display = 'none';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'block';
            }

  //hide text onclick
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $p = $('p#menu_title');
                $("input#save_first_prod").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $p.css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: visible; 
}
div#first_product{
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
    
}

div#red_head{
background-color: #ed1c24;
height: 40px;
color: #fff;
padding-left: 15px;
line-height: 35px;
}

div#first_product{
background-color: #f1f1f2; 
height: 100%;
}

h3#menu{
color: #6d6e70;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')">Hello!</button>

<div id="first_product">
            <div id="red_head">
                <p id="menu_title" class ="hidden" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
            </div>
            <h3 id="menu">Menu Section</h3>

            <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               

                <label id="cat_label" name="cat_label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" value="">

                <label id="desc_label" name="desc_label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_desc" name="cat_desc" value="">

                <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')" value=" + ADD"> 

            </form>


        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You seemed to understand what i was trying to do, better then i did. This is exactly what i was looking for